# How to extract/generate Meta data from an .NET assembly just like VS "Go to definition" do

Tags: c#, assemblies, metadata

Does anyone know how to extract/generate Meta data from an .NET assembly just like VS "Go to definition" do. When you do this within Visual Studio you get generated CS class files in the temp directory with Meta data classes.

I´m looking for an automatically way to extract/generate CS classes from an entier Assembly.

Is there any tool for this? I have looked at ILDASM, BINDUMP, SVCUTIL etc and a bunch of decompilers. But i cannot find a tool to do what I want.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the .NET Reflector:  http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: if you want an exe to decompile it for you, then reflector is the tool. it will decompile the whole dll for you. you may need one of the plugins though.

Answer (score 2):

VS's Go to definition basically just uses the standard [.NET reflection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to extract the public API of the class and present it to you.

There is no decompilation necessary to duplicate this, since the implementation is not provided, just the public API.

Comment: Yes, I know that but was looking for an out of the box software/EXE that would go through the Assembly for me and generate CS classes. But maybe I just have to spende a few hours writing the "loop" myself

Comment: If you want some sample code for looking through types, and extracting data, there's some here: http://trac.assembla.com/plugintoolkit/browser/trunk/Pluto.Core/Development